# Text zooming issue on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

Experiencing an odd text zooming issue in Chrome.

I'll visit a page and the text is extra large, despite the zoom being set to 100%.

**Here is a screencast summarizing the issue in action: http://screencast.com/t/W6lnjPap**

The following actions will resolve it:

- Zoom up to 110%, then back down to 100% and it'll look normal.
- Zooming down to 90% and then back up to 100% also works.
- Reloading the page

Here's what i know:

- It happens randomly
- It's only happening on one site
- Can only recreate in Chrome
- Deactivated all browser extensions

Steps to recreate:

- Visit http://thewc.co
- Click login on the top right. If the bug did not occur, the login and signup form should sit nicely next to one another. If the bug *did* occur, the text is larger and the signup form gets bumped down awkwardly below the login form.
- If the bug does not appear, try again to recreate the issue by hitting back and then hitting "Log in" again from the home page. As I mentioned, it's random, but usually a few tries will reveal itself.

The fact that it's happening on a single site makes me think is site-specific/css-specific...But the randomness of it makes me question that.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on my Chrome (32.0.1700.19 beta-m Aura). I notice that something similar to the symptom (signup pushed down) can sometimes be seen as the page is rendering and then the boxes rearrange into normal form.  Makes me suspect you may be having a .css or .js file loading failure (randomly).  Next time you experience it, right-click on the page, "Inspect Element"; then in the Developer Tools select "Console" tab and look for red errors about files not loading. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Narrowed it down to an issue on Chrome's end

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099844/chrome-not-respecting-rem-font-size-on-body-tag
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320754

Solution (per the SO post linked above) at least until Chrome resolves it:

Use the universal selector to set the font-size in rem, instead of the body.